# Android: best practice for nested recyclerview linked to cloud firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I currently use a nested RecyclerView with an SQLite Database. However, I am currently switching to firebase, using Cloud Firestore as a database.

My setup is:

- the Firestore database setup is: **Users -> Houses -> Rooms -> Tasks**
- vertical rv = rooms, horizontal rv = tasks
- one model for the vertical rv, one model for the horizontal rv
- as vertical rv I am using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
- inside its onbindviewholder I am calling:

```
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(verticalPosition);

    String roomId = snapshot.getId();
```

- with the Id I am queuing for the horizontal array list (tasks), which is located inside the Firestore reference "room":

```
if (currentUser != null) {
        String userID = currentUser.getUid();
        userRef = fdb.collection("users").document(userID);
        houseRef = userRef.collection("houses").document("house0");
        roomRef = houseRef.collection("rooms").document(roomId);

            roomRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(tasksnap -> {
                if (tasksnap.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = tasksnap.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {

                        VerticalModel room = document.toObject(VerticalModel.class);
                        if (room != null) {
                            ArrayList<HorizontalModel> tasks = room.getArrayList();

                            hAdapter = new HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter(context, new ArrayList<>(),
                                    verticalPosition, listener, cleanInter);
                            holder.view.rvHorizontal.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            holder.view.rvHorizontal.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,
                                    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

                            holder.view.rvHorizontal.setAdapter(hAdapter);
                            holder.view.rvHorizontal.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

                            holder.updateContents(tasks, hAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Instead of one array list per room with all tasks, I will switch to one document for one tasks.

However, I am experiencing many Firestore read calls, probably as the onbind method is called a couple of times.

So if there are any experts: Is there a better approach? Using 2 Firestore adapters did not work for me, unfortunately.

Maybe it is possible to force firebase to read from the local cache all the time and only when the user exits the app, it update the changes?

Comment: What are you worried about?  The number of reads?

Comment: Two things: the number of reads and if there is a better way to implement the second rv (e.g. second firebase adapter).

Comment: What is the maximum number of Tasks a single room (document) can have?

Comment: Free users can only add 5 rooms, each with 5 tasks. Paid users will mostly add around 8 rooms, each with around 10 to 20 tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your first comment:

> the number of reads and if there is a better way to implement the second rv

And the second comment:

> Free users can only add 5 rooms, each with 5 tasks. Paid users will mostly add around 8 rooms, each with around 10 to 20 tasks.

The simplest option I can think of would be to use an array type field in each Room object that can hold all Task objects. Since it will exist only a few Task objects, you can easily add them to a single document. In this way, you only have to pay a single read for displaying a room together with all tasks.

If you're wondering how to map an array of custom objects into a List, please read the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Maybe you can give me another hint: If I update the arraylist, it refreshes the whole adapter, always jumping inside the nested rv to the left. Do you know a trick, to use something like "notifyitemchanged" inside the firebase adapter to avoid refreshing the whole adapter?

Comment: Most likely you should notify the adapter for each element you or remove, using notifyItemRangeInserted or notifyItemRangeRemoved.

Comment: The problem is that the listener is calling datasetchanged. Is there any way to avoid this call?

Comment: It's not bad to call notifyDataSetChanged, but only if your entire data has changed, otherwise call them independently. If you have a hard time implementing this, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.